# Как сделать выборку из таблицы с условием на совпадения в диапазоне?

Tags: mysql, sql

Пролог:

Есть таблица в БД, с основными полями `service_time[тип поля:time]`,`master[тип поля:varchar]`,`date[тип поля:date]`,`time[тип поля:time]`. В результате прямого модифицирования таблицы (по своей глупости, но уже исправлять поздно) путем запросов `UPDATE`, предполагаю, что целостность БД - пострадала. Это приведет к необратимым логическим сбоям.

---

Пример хранимых данных:

```
create table cl
(
    ID_client       int auto_increment
        primary key
    service_time    time        not null,
    master          varchar(24) not null,
    date            date        not null,
    time            time        not null,
);

INSERT INTO cl (service_time, master, date, time) VALUES ('02:00:00', 'Lana', '2020-07-18', '14:30:00');
INSERT INTO cl (service_time, master, date, time) VALUES ('02:00:00', 'Lana', '2020-07-19', '14:30:00');
INSERT INTO cl (service_time, master, date, time) VALUES ('02:00:00', 'Lana', '2020-07-18', '15:00:00');
INSERT INTO cl (service_time, master, date, time) VALUES ('02:00:00', 'Lana', '2020-07-18', '16:45:00');
INSERT INTO cl (service_time, master, date, time) VALUES ('02:00:00', 'Alex', '2020-07-07', '20:00:00');
```

---

Запрос:

Для того, что бы проверить пострадала ли логическая ценность таблицы, нужен запрос который бы возвращал из таблицы строки в которых `time`+`service_time` было бы меньше, чем следующее `time` на этот же день, для этого же мастера.

Пример ответа для хранимых данных указанных выше:

```
| service_time | master | date       | time     |
| 02:00:00     | Lana   | 2020-07-18 | 14:30:00 |
| 02:00:00     | Lana   | 2020-07-18 | 15:00:00 |
| 02:00:00     | Lana   | 2020-07-18 | 16:45:00 |
```

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая версию. Добавьте соотв. тег. Добавьте в вопрос скрипт создания таблицы (CREATE TABLE) и скрипт её наполнения тест-данными (INSERT INTO). Покажите требуемый ответ для именно таких данных. *Надеюсь, в формате JSON всем удобно читать* Нет.

Comment: @Akina, изменил на удобный формат, исходя из вашего комментария.

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, **включая версию**.

Comment: @Akina, Прошу заметить, что в тегах я также указал **mysql**, версия - 5.0.11.

Comment: Пять точка ноль? увы, не помогу - по этой версии официальная документация давно убрана с сайта. Но уж коли начал: вот [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=050696b26c7a1e8b96906b997f8ef61f), может, кто продолжит...

Comment: @Akina, я с легкостью адаптирую код в версиях 8.0 и старше, под то, что мне нужно, поэтому версия - это исключительно моя проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> я с легкостью адаптирую код в версиях 8.0 и старше, под то, что мне нужно

Да не вопрос.

```
WITH
cte AS ( SELECT *,
                TIMESTAMP(`date`, `time`) start_datetime, 
                TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`date`, ' ', `time`), service_time) final_datetime
         FROM cl )
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID_client
FROM cte t1, cte t2
WHERE t1.start_datetime < t2.final_datetime
  AND t2.start_datetime < t1.final_datetime
  AND t1.master = t2.master
  AND t1.ID_client != t2.ID_client;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd24a60fbe84d9efa73d8601cca1b4e8)

Вместо `ID_client` можно вывести любые поля - как исходные, так и расчётные.